# WebException.Status not serialized

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2008, serialization, deserialization

When I run the test below (NUnit and VS2008 SP1) I get the following error

Expected: ConnectFailure
But was:  UnknownError

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
[Test]
public void SerializationWebExceptionTest()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        const WebExceptionStatus Expected = WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure;
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var initialException = new WebException("Test", null, Expected, null);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, initialException);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var result = (WebException)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

        var actual = result.Status;

        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(Expected));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing everything fine. To me looks like it is a bug in .NET framework. Stumbled upon this in .NET 4.6 when dealing with exceptions that are thrown in another AppDomain. 
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebException.cs,47e37066345d8b7c shows that the code for serialization of this field is commented out.